# List files on https server using R

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to list files (.laz files) on an HTTPS server, then download them. I receive the warning message: "XML content does not seem to be XML:" when I try to obtain a list of .laz files.

Here is my code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

www <- "https://resources.gisdata.mn.gov/pub/data/elevation/lidar/county/chisago/laz/"

files <-  getHTMLLinks(www, xpQuery = "//a/@href['.laz'=substring(., string-length(.) - 3)]"
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(files), nrow=length(files), byrow=T))
```

Maybe this problem has to do with the site being HTTPS, instead of HTTP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain the error `getHTMLLinks` is generating.

Here is a solution with rvest package:

```
library(rvest)  #rvest verison 1.0.0
library(magrittr)

#read the page
www <- "https://resources.gisdata.mn.gov/pub/data/elevation/lidar/county/chisago/laz/"
page <- read_html(www)

#find the hrefs attributes which contain ".laz"
filenames <-html_elements(page, xpath = ".//a[contains(@href, '.laz')]") %>% html_text() 
links <- paste0(www, filenames)
```